# Cannot pip install atlassian-python-api due to subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, subprocess, atlassian-python-api

I am trying to install the `atlassian-python-api` using **pip** but upon trying to do so, I get  the following error: ***Getting requirements to build wheel ... error: subprocess-exited-with-error***.

I am running Python version `3.10.0a2` installed through [`pyenv-win`](https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win). I am not exactly sure what could be causing this, but here is my full command output for a better understanding:

```sh
(venv) PS > pip install atlassian-python-api
Collecting atlassian-python-api
  Using cached atlassian-python-api-3.20.1.tar.gz (131 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 177, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 159, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 281, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
          setup(
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 154, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in _install_setup_requires
          dist = MinimalDistribution(attrs)
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 135, in __init__
          super().__init__(filtered)
        File "AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mzcohtxb\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 456, in __init__
          for ep in metadata.entry_points(group='distutils.setup_keywords'):
      TypeError: entry_points() got an unexpected keyword argument 'group'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Comment: The error message means that the package's `setup.py` is not compatible with the `setuptools` you have on your system. Without more details, we can't say if one is really old and another is really new (for example) or if there is a more fundamental bug in one of them (probably then the package you were trying to install, as `setuptools` is reasonably widely used and tested).